# Vuejs how to create a multilingual website

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want something like this.

1. I create the website in English language.
2. If the web site visitor comes from Germany server detects it and passes to the Vue.js then vue serve the website in German language.
3. of cause he (web site visiter) can change the German to the English by selecting the language in a drop down.
4. Specialty is there is no google translate appear as a pop up and asks to translate this to that.

Is this possible in Vue.js?

Comment: This is going to be your best resource: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#i18n

Comment: you can use vue-i18n module to build multilingual website. checkout https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/

Comment: Thanks i18n will be the solution. =)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a multilingual VueJS application, you would need to use [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/).

Comment: Thanks! Hope this'll be the solution for my problem.